# Dynamic update of CKEditor skin

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Is there a way to dynamically change the skin of the editor (CKEditor 4.1 (revision 80c139aa))?

The only way I could do that is from the config.js (which means that my skins are working ok)

The editor is loaded when a jDialog is opened. On open of the dialog i want to run a command that will change the skin according to user preferences.

I tried with no luck:

```
CKEDITOR.config.skin = '/moono-dark';
```

Also this:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
  config.skin = '/karma';
};
```

Also this:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'problem', {
  customConfig: '../ckeditor/skins/config_flat.js'; //this path is ok
});
```

Also tried to load the config file with ajax (after deleting the defaulkt config.js file):

```
$.getScript( "../ckeditor/skins/config_icy_orange.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
      CKEDITOR.replace( 'problem' );
});
```

It always loads the default config.js file...

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the skin to use whith CKEDITOR.replace like this:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'ckeditor',{
        skin: "kama"
});
```

If the skin isn't in the default plugin folder you should add the path to the skin folder like this:

```
// Enable "moonocolor" skin from the /myskins/moonocolor/ folder.
 CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    skin: 'moonocolor,/myskins/moonocolor/' 
} );
```

Here a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andreagva/doqu07gL/) with kama

You can see here [ckeditor skin samples](http://rev.ckeditor.com/ckeditor/trunk/6341/_samples/skins.html)

Comment: as you have it on your fiddle, can we have a button that will change that skin to `moono` ?

Comment: Was looking in the docs, but seems that CKEditor 4 only allows one skin per page. The ability to load multiple skins on the same page was removed from the v4. You could try to achieve this with some tricks like delete window.CKEDITOR and reinitializing the whole library, but isn't a good practice.
Else instead of changing the skin you can try to change the ui color to achieve something similar.

Comment: Is the same, unless you force the user to reload the whole page with new config, ckeditor stores the first skin you use somewhere and doesn't allow you to change it "on-flight" because is the same as using 2 skins on the same page(you didn't reload the page, the page is the same). I tried with destroy() and remove() methods and couldn't achieve it, but with the same methods i can change other configs and it works. So as i said before you could do something tricky like destroy ckeditor entire library and reloading it, but isn't a good practice.

Comment: If you really need this behavior you can consider the easy way to open the ckeditor form in a new iframe and not in the same page passing it a var for the skin, but this is a bad trick too.

Comment: what do you mean "with the same methods i can change other configs and it works" ? Can you post a fiddle please? As for the iframe option, I would prefer to avoid it.

Comment: i mean that overriding other configs in ckeditor like the uiColor, the toolbar elements etc. is possible. But for some reasons they don't allow to override the skin config. Check out this fiddle with a button to change the editor color : http://jsfiddle.net/krm0kmux/